Drupal Googlemaps, server side clustering
I got on this project after it was already made fully with drupal, but it was limited for what I needed so I rewrote the drupal page with built-in google maps to a new blank page, where i load in a google maps with div id map. with this js file as a custom module nodehook.
// Declare map and MarkerClusterer globally
let map;
let markerClusterer = null;
let debounceTimeout;

// Initialize the map
function initMap() {
    const mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: 52.370216, lng: 4.895168 },  // Initial center
        zoom: 3,  // Initial zoom level
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 20,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain',
        fullscreenControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        styles: [
            { featureType: "administrative", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "administrative.country", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "administrative.international_border", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }] },
            { featureType: "administrative.international_border", elementType: "geometry.fill", stylers: [{ color: "#000000" }] },
            { featureType: "administrative.neighborhood", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "administrative.parcel", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "administrative.reservation", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "administrative.reservation", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "administrative.sublocality", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "administrative.top_level_admin", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "administrative.top_level_admin", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "land", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }] },
            { featureType: "land", elementType: "geometry.fill", stylers: [{ color: "#EE5124" }] },
            { featureType: "land", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "land.archipelago", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "land.background", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }] },
            { featureType: "land.continent", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "land.island", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "land.land_cover", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "land.water", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }] },
            { featureType: "land.water", elementType: "geometry.fill", stylers: [{ color: "#000000" }] },
            { featureType: "land.water", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "poi", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "poi", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.all_buildings", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.all_buildings", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.built_up_area", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.corridor", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.rail", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.rail", elementType: "geometry.fill", stylers: [{ color: "#FF6633" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.rail", elementType: "geometry.stroke", stylers: [{ color: "#FF6633" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.road", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.road", elementType: "geometry.fill", stylers: [{ color: "#FF6633" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.road", elementType: "geometry.stroke", stylers: [{ color: "#FF6633" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.road", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "transportation.transit_station_or_entrance", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
            { featureType: "water", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }] },
            { featureType: "water", elementType: "geometry.fill", stylers: [{ color: "#000000" }] },
            { featureType: "water", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] }
        ]
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    // Load markers with debounce to avoid multiple unnecessary requests
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
        clearTimeout(debounceTimeout);
        debounceTimeout = setTimeout(loadMapMarkers, 300);  // Wait for 300ms before sending a request
    });
}

// Load Google Maps script dynamically
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log("Loading Google Maps script...");

    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= :) &callback=initMap";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // Load the marker clustering library
    const clusterScript = document.createElement("script");
    clusterScript.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markerclustererplus/2.1.4/markerclusterer.min.js";
    clusterScript.async = true;
    clusterScript.defer = true;
    document.body.appendChild(clusterScript);
});

function loadMapMarkers() {
    console.log("Map is idle, fetching markers...");

    const bounds = map.getBounds();
    const zoom = map.getZoom();

    // Ensure bounds are valid before making a request
    if (!bounds) {
        console.error("Invalid map bounds.");
        return;
    }

    const boundsParams = {
        north: bounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
        south: bounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
        east: bounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
        west: bounds.getSouthWest().lng()
    };

    console.log("Sending request with bounds:", boundsParams, "and zoom:", zoom);

    // Fetch marker clusters from the server
    fetch(`/map/cluster?zoom=${zoom}&bounds=${JSON.stringify(boundsParams)}`)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                console.error('Error fetching clusters:', response.statusText);
                return;
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(clusters => {
            if (!clusters || clusters.length === 0) {
                console.warn('No clusters received.');
                return;
            }
            console.log('Received clusters:', clusters);
            updateMarkers(clusters);  // Update the map with new markers
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error loading clusters:', error));
}

function updateMarkers(clusters) {
    // Clear previous markers from the clusterer
    if (markerClusterer) {
        markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
    }

    const markers = clusters.map(cluster => {
        const markerPosition = {
            lat: parseFloat(cluster.lat),
            lng: parseFloat(cluster.lng)
        };

        if (cluster.count > 1) {
            // Handle cluster marker
            return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markerPosition,
                label: {
                    text: cluster.count.toString(),  // Show the number of markers in the cluster
                    color: "white",
                    fontSize: "14px",
                    fontWeight: "bold"
                },
                icon: {
                    url: '/sites/default/files/geofieldmap_icons/cluster',
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40)
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Handle individual marker
            return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markerPosition,
                title: cluster.title || "Marker",  // Use 'title' if available
                icon: {
                    url: '/sites/default/files/geofieldmap_icons/marker.svg',
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30)
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Initialize MarkerClusterer if it's not already initialized
    markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
    });
}


This is where all my client stuff happends, and below is the server side code I use for the api request handling. Instead of using geo spatial data, which I couldn't figure out I thought it might be a good idea to make a grid and just use client side data from bounds and zoom level to fetch the data this way, for load balancing atleast 47000 markers.
Here's the MapClusterController.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\google_map_clustering\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\google_map_clustering\Service\ClusterService;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MapClusterController extends ControllerBase {

  protected $clusterService;

  public function __construct(ClusterService $clusterService) {
    $this->clusterService = $clusterService;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('google_map_clustering.cluster_service')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Fetch clusters based on map zoom level and bounds.
   *
   * @param Request $request
   *   The request object containing zoom level and bounds.
   *
   * @return JsonResponse
   *   A JSON response containing the clusters or an error.
   */
  public function getClusters(Request $request) {
    $zoom = $request->query->get('zoom');
    $bounds = $request->query->get('bounds');

    // Log incoming parameters for debugging.
    \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->info('Zoom: ' . $zoom);
    \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->info('Bounds: ' . $bounds);

    if (empty($zoom) || empty($bounds)) {
      \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->error('Missing zoom or bounds parameters.');
      return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Missing zoom or bounds parameters'], 400);
    }

    try {
      $clusters = $this->clusterService->getClusters($zoom, $bounds);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->error('Error fetching clusters: ' . $e->getMessage());
      return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Internal server error'], 500);
    }

    return new JsonResponse($clusters);
  }
}



and here's the ClusterService.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\google_map_clustering\Service;

use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class ClusterService {

  protected $httpClient;

  public function __construct(ClientInterface $httpClient) {
    $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
  }

  /**
   * Fetches and clusters markers based on zoom level and map bounds.
   *
   * @param int $zoom
   *   The zoom level of the map.
   * @param string $bounds
   *   The map bounds as a JSON string.
   *
   * @return array
   *   An array of clustered markers.
   */
  public function getClusters($zoom, $bounds) {
    \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->info('Received zoom level: ' . $zoom);
    \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->info('Received bounds: ' . $bounds);

    // Decode bounds since they are passed as a JSON string.
    $bounds = json_decode($bounds, true);

    if (empty($bounds) || !$this->areBoundsValid($bounds)) {
      \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->error('Invalid bounds: ' . json_encode($bounds));
      return [];
    }

    // Fetch markers from the REST API.
    $response = $this->httpClient->get('https://drupal.graffitidb.localhost/api/newworld');
    \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->info('API call status: ' . $response->getStatusCode());

    if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
      \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->error('Failed to fetch markers from API: ' . $response->getReasonPhrase());
      return [];
    }

    // Decode API response.
    $responseBody = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->info('API response: ' . $responseBody);

    $markers = json_decode($responseBody, true);
    if (!$markers || !is_array($markers)) {
      \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->error('Malformed API response.');
      return [];
    }

    // Log number of markers received.
    \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->info('Number of markers received: ' . count($markers));

    // Parse marker geolocations.
    foreach ($markers as &$marker) {
      if (isset($marker['field_geolocation'])) {
        $coords = explode(',', $marker['field_geolocation']);
        if (isset($coords[0], $coords[1])) {
          $marker['lat'] = floatval(trim($coords[0]));
          $marker['lng'] = floatval(trim($coords[1]));
        } else {
          \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->warning('Invalid geolocation format for marker: ' . json_encode($marker));
          continue;
        }
      }
    }

    // Calculate grid size.
    $gridSize = $this->calculateGridSize($zoom);
    \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->info('Calculated grid size: ' . $gridSize);

    // Perform clustering.
    $clusters = $this->clusterMarkers($markers, $gridSize, $bounds);
    \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->info('Clusters generated: ' . count($clusters));

    return $clusters;
  }

  /**
   * Validate the map bounds.
   *
   * @param array $bounds
   *   The bounds array with 'north', 'south', 'east', 'west'.
   *
   * @return bool
   *   TRUE if bounds are valid, FALSE otherwise.
   */
  private function areBoundsValid($bounds) {
    return isset($bounds['north'], $bounds['south'], $bounds['east'], $bounds['west']) &&
           is_numeric($bounds['north']) && is_numeric($bounds['south']) &&
           is_numeric($bounds['east']) && is_numeric($bounds['west']) &&
           $bounds['north'] > $bounds['south'] &&
           $bounds['east'] > $bounds['west'];
  }

  /**
   * Calculate the grid size based on the zoom level.
   *
   * @param int $zoom
   *   The zoom level of the map.
   *
   * @return int
   *   The grid size used for clustering.
   */
  private function calculateGridSize($zoom) {
    if (!is_numeric($zoom) || $zoom < 0) {
      \Drupal::logger('google_map_clustering')->error('Invalid zoom level: ' . $zoom);
      return 100;  // Default grid size if zoom is invalid.
    }

    if ($zoom >= 15) {
      return 20;  // Fine-grained clusters at high zoom.
    } elseif ($zoom >= 10) {
      return 50;
    } else {
      return 100;  // Coarse clusters for low zoom levels.
    }
  }

  /**
   * Perform marker clustering based on grid size and bounds.
   *
   * @param array $markers
   *   The list of markers to cluster.
   * @param int $gridSize
   *   The size of the grid for clustering.
   * @param array $bounds
   *   The map bounds to filter markers.
   *
   * @return array
   *   An array of clustered markers.
   */
  private function clusterMarkers($markers, $gridSize, $bounds) {
    $clusters = [];

    foreach ($markers as $marker) {
      if ($this->isWithinBounds($marker, $bounds)) {
        // Calculate grid coordinates for clustering.
        $gridX = floor($marker['lng'] / $gridSize);
        $gridY = floor($marker['lat'] / $gridSize);

        $gridKey = $gridX . '_' . $gridY;

        if (!isset($clusters[$gridKey])) {
          $clusters[$gridKey] = [
            'lat' => $marker['lat'],
            'lng' => $marker['lng'],
            'count' => 0,
            'ids' => [],
            'title' => $marker['title'] ?? 'Unknown'
          ];
        }

        $clusters[$gridKey]['count']++;
        if (isset($marker['nid'])) {
          $clusters[$gridKey]['ids'][] = $marker['nid'];
        }
      }
    }

    return array_values($clusters);
  }

  /**
   * Check if a marker is within the map bounds.
   *
   * @param array $marker
   *   The marker data with 'lat' and 'lng'.
   * @param array $bounds
   *   The map bounds to filter by.
   *
   * @return bool
   *   TRUE if the marker is within the bounds, FALSE otherwise.
   */
  private function isWithinBounds($marker, $bounds) {
    return isset($marker['lat'], $marker['lng']) &&
           $marker['lat'] >= $bounds['south'] &&
           $marker['lat'] <= $bounds['north'] &&
           $marker['lng'] >= $bounds['west'] &&
           $marker['lng'] <= $bounds['east'];
  }
}


Been logging with watchdog in drupal and not giving me anything anymore from error logging this file. Keep getting error 500 in my browser.
Map is idle, fetching markers...
Sending request with bounds: {north: 75.82526976195598, south: -3.594579947004095, east: 114.18144966497823, west: -105.19355033502177} and zoom: 3
   GET https://drupal.graffitidb.localhost/map/cluster?zoom=3&bounds={%22north%22:75.82526976195598,%22south%22:-3.594579947004095,%22east%22:114.18144966497823,%22west%22:-105.19355033502177} 500 (Internal Server Error)

Can't seem to find where it's going wrong :/
Trying to load in google maps clusters based on map position and zoom level.
